# SharePoint Online Turn off customErrors to view more about the error not working

Tags: publishing, provider-hosted-app, web-config, online

When deploying a provider hosted SharePoint App on SharePoint online via an Azure web page, I get a **Runtime error** message, instructing me to turn off customErrors to view more about the error. I have done this in the web.config, and it still displays the error. When debugging the app locally it deploys fine, it is just when I try to release it onto my online SP environment.

When researching online I have read about going into these paths

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\(14)(15)(16)\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\web.config
```

But all three of these locations are don't hold a `web.config` file.

Any help with this one?

Answer (score 1):

With a provider hosted application (on Azure or otherwise), you can think of it mostly like a standalone application. So it's only your own web.config that you need to change.

I have noticed the same behaviour with Azure websites though. I presume it's a security measure. If you FTP to your website, you'll find the error pages in the Logfiles/DetailedErrors folder. They have all the detail you'd normally get when CustomErrors is set to off.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/waws/archive/2014/05/22/azure-web-sites-troubleshooting-server-error-in-application-errors.aspx

Comment: thanks for this, although it hasn't solved my issue, it pushed me in the right direction and I was able to look at the azure web logs, now the issue is with SharePoint authentication in the app.